# How can I stop iTunes 10 launching when pressing the Play/Pause buttons?

Tags: keyboard, itunes

When I'm watching a movie and I press the "play" button, iTunes 10 launches. How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: This question was asked (in a Snow Leopard context) on super user: http://superuser.com/questions/31925 .  Unfortunately, the problem seems to be quite difficult to solve cleanly...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found [this](http://lifehacker.com/5651055/free-your-macs-media-keys-from-itunes-no-manual-hacking-required) on Lifehacker.  I think it's exactly what you're looking for.  The post talks about a patch called MMFix, which changes the media control daemon to stop exactly this from happening.  Apparently, it comes with a one-click installer.

And, if some reason you would like to remove the patch, just run the one-click installer again and the original rcd daemon will be restored.

(Works on OS X 10.7 Lion, too!)

Comment: Sounds great, i will try it :-)

Answer (score 3):

MMFix hasn't been updated for Mountain Lion yet, but I did find this [solution](http://gavinroy.com/disabling-default-itunes-launch-behavior-with) to work, run

> `launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`

in the Terminal.

Comment: Keep in mind though that this disables the functionality of the media keys in iTunes itself as well.

Comment: @BartArondson how to enable it back, with 'load' ?

Comment: @user2113 Yes, probably. Although I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

[iTunesPatch](http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch) did the trick for me on OS X Yosemite.

Description from website:

> The application will patch the Remote Control Daemon to prevent it from starting iTunes whenever you press the play button on the keyboard or an external remote control. This will only prevent iTunes from starting, all other functions (like play/pause while iTunes is running) will continue to work as before. The original file is backed up in case you would like to restore the original functionality.